# How to fix "GC overhead limit exceeded" Error?

Tags: android-studio

when i want to generate signed Apk ,this error GC "overhead limit exceeded" goes up.

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
>
> public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
>   .
>   . } (and declared it in manifest)

in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx256m
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

Comment: dexOptions { 
          incremental true 
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}

Comment: if you add javaMaxHeapSize you need to make sure of two other things: First, compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' in dependencies{ } of build.gradle. And second, android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in application tag of manifest.